# ORA-00905: missing keyword error

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I keep getting this pesky error whenever I try this code:

```
 select 
    gam.acid,
        gam.foracid,
        gam.acct_name,
        gam.sol_id,
        sol.sol_desc,
        gam.gl_sub_head_code,
        case gsh.gl_code
             when cast(gl_code as int) >= 01 and cast(gl_code as int) <=13
                      or cast(gl_code as int) >= 15 and cast(gl_code as int) <=24 then 'A'
                 when cast(gl_code as int) >= 28 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 31
                     or cast(gl_code as int) >= 33 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 39
                     or cast(gl_code as int) = 41
                     or cast(gl_code as int) >= 43 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 48 then 'L'
                 when cast(gl_code as int) = 51
                     or cast(gl_code as int) = 53
                     or cast(gl_code as int) >= 55 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 57 then 'C'
                 when cast(gl_code as int) >= 61 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 70
                     or cast(gl_code as int) >= 72 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 81 then 'I'
                 when cast(gl_code as int) = 84 or cast(gl_code as int) = 85
                     or cast(gl_code as int) >= 87 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 94 then 'E'
                 when cast(gl_code as int) >= 97 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 99 then 'S'
                 else null
          end as gl_classification
    from tbaadm.gam
```

I have the feeling that some things are out of place in the code, or I forgot to do/add something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the error reported against (once you've changed the `case gsh.gl_code` to just `case` as mentioned in answers)? Are you sure it's from the `case`, not the joins/where clause that you haven't shown?

Comment: it's at this line `when cast(gl_code as int) >= 01 and cast(gl_code as int) <=13` Toad always points to the `>=` sign right next to `01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CASE` construct](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS339) has two alternatives syntaxes:

```
CASE foo WHEN 1 THEN 'blah' END
CASE WHEN foo=1 THEN 'blah' END
```

You're trying to use both at the same time:

```
case gsh.gl_code
when cast(gl_code as int) >= 01
```

It should be:

```
  select case
         --gsh.gl_code  remove this 
            when cast(gl_code as int) >= 01 and cast(gl_code as int) <=13
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 15 and cast(gl_code as int) <=24 then 'A'
            when cast(gl_code as int) >= 28 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 31
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 33 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 39
                or cast(gl_code as int) = 41
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 43 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 48 then 'L'
            when cast(gl_code as int) = 51
                or cast(gl_code as int) = 53
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 55 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 57 then 'C'
            when cast(gl_code as int) >= 61 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 70
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 72 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 81 then 'I'
            when cast(gl_code as int) = 84 or cast(gl_code as int) = 85
                or cast(gl_code as int) >= 87 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 94 then 'E'
            when cast(gl_code as int) >= 97 and cast(gl_code as int) <= 99 then 'S'
            else null
        end as gl_classification
   from tbaadm.gam
```

Comment: doesn't work. would it help if I said that I originally included other items in the `select` statement? i'll update the code now.

Comment: Probably helpful to explain why removing that column reference is necessary (confused use of the two types of case). @JamesP - with that removed, you still get the same error?

Comment: @JamesP - Gaurav is right, you cannot use CASE that way. Seriously.

Comment: nope, I get a different error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: @JamesP - did you remove just the `gsh.gl_code` part, or the line with `case gsh.gl_code`, taking out the `case` keyword as well?

Comment: I had answered basically the same, so I've taken the liberty of merging my info into your question to avoid such an obvious dupe. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: wow. I can't believe I missed one tiny detail. This `case` is originally in the middle of a `select` statement, and I forgot to put a comma after the `end as` part. adding that missing comma, along with Gaurav's suggestion, did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using brackets to give a priority to the AND/OR conditions. For example:

```
when (cast(gl_code as int) >= 01 and cast(gl_code as int) <=13)
    or (cast(gl_code as int) >= 15 and cast(gl_code as int) <=24) then 'A'
```

it might help...